# python, mongoengine - do like/regex search

Tags: python, mongoengine

I know I can do a glob-type search on mongodb:

```
db.person.find({ name: /*.bob.*/ })
```

or

```
db.person.find({ name: { $regex: '*.bob.*' }})
```

How do I do this with mongoengine without using a raw query (which is apparently the only way based on my searches)?

I've blindly tried several variations like:

```
Person.objects(name='/.*bob.*/')
Person.objects(name='/\.*bob\.*/')
Person.objects(name='.*bob.*')
Person.objects(name='\\.*bob\\.*')
```

etc, to no avail...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It looks like you can do it this way:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('.*bob.*')
Person.objects(name=regex)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me. If you wanted the search to be case insensitive. Use `regex = re.compile('.*bob.*', re.IGNORECASE)`