# Mongoengine query listfield contains string matches

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a `ListField` in models which contians `string` values. How do I query a `string` matches which are contains given `string`? I know `contains` operator do the need. But it matches exactly the given string is present.

#### For Example:

```
[
    {_id: 1, "name": "name1", "tags": ["abc", "efg", "ijk"]},
    {_id: 2, "name": "name2", "tags": ["bcd", "fgh", "jkl"]}
]
```

#### Model:

```
class Users(Document):
    name = StringField()
    tags = ListField(StringField())
```

Then my query is like

```
users = Users.objects(tags__icontains='bc')
```

Which I expect it returns both records contains `bc`

**Note**: For `icontains` operator works as expected when it is `StringField`, but for `ListField` it turns simply matches `User.objects(tags='bc')`. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903527/1117099)

In addition to this, there is an option in mongo query with text matching, MongoDB query supports Perl notation of the regular expression. Like `tags=/bc/`. How do we do this with mongoengine. [Refer](https://blog.exploratory.io/an-introduction-to-mongodb-query-for-beginners-bd463319aa4c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have done this with Regular expression matches.

I have changed my query with

`users = Users.objects(tags__icontains='bc')`

**instead of**

```
import re

users = Users.objects(tags=re.compile('.*bc.*', re.IGNORECASE))
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39133617/1117099)